# What's the difference between "the one thing" and "the thing"?

Tags: meaning

Could anyone help to tell the difference between these two sentences:
"That's the thing I want to do" and "That's the one thing I want to do"
Thanks

Comment: The only difference is that in the second example you've extra-qualified it as one single thing.  ..How is this a real question?  Is this spam?  ; )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a very subtle difference.

In the first sentence-

> "That's the thing I want to do"

You are implying to do a(that) thing from among other possible choices that you have. For instance- if you're having a family conversation about a picnic, and various options are being considered; someone says out loud -"Let's go for a hike". And, since you like hiking, you say-  *"Yes, that's the thing I want to do"*.

Now, coming to your second sentence-

> "That's the one thing I want to do"

Here, "the one thing" is comparable to do something that you have always wanted to do. It is sort of a very importable objective in your life, something like one's *[Bucket List](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bucket%20list)*

So, you can use "that's the one thing I want to do" as-

> "Climbing the Mt. Everest: That's the one thing I want to do before I
>   turn 40".

Take a look at this example of "The one thing" from this [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/williamarruda/2013/10/22/the-one-thing-successful-people-do-every-day/) link

> **The One Thing Successful People Do Every Day**
>
> We’re all busy. We all have infinite to-do lists that fill up faster
>   than we can cross off the most urgent tasks. Being busy makes you feel
>   productive, but it could be getting in the way of your most important
>   project: YOU.
>
> “Busy” is the most common reason people give me for not doing anything
>   to build their brand so they can advance their career.  They make time
>   for emails and meetings and teleconferences, but they don’t capture
>   the true benefits of all those activities. Working in their career is
>   getting in the way of working on their career. Sound familiar?
>
> Well, here’s ***the one*** personal branding habit you can’t be too
>   busy for.
>
> Document your wins. What’s the easiest way to do that?  Keep a job
>   journal.

Comment: While the above illustrates one usage of 'the one thing', with 'one' used as a particulariser, equivalent to 'single', 'one' is also used as a more basic emphasiser, equivalent to 'very' ('That's the very thing I want to do!'), stressed 'the' ('That's **the** thing I really want to do!') etc ('That's _exactly_ what I wanted to do!) .... The usages merge, though.